# PhpStorm - How to create connection with remote database is located on the PhpMyAdmin server

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

I'm a new user of PhpStorm and I'm trying to create a connection to my remote database is located on the PhpMyAdmin server.

When I configure the "Data Sources and Drivers" window in PhpStorm with the following information:

- **Name**: "Login"
- **User**: ***** (User for cPanel)
- **Password**: ***** (Password for cPanel)
- **URL**: jdbc:mysql://sharedserver15.host-stage-dns.com:2083/cpsess1657590563/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=zkorwzjc_multi_login

I get an error:

> [08S01] Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> java.io.EOFException: Can not read the response from the server. Expected to read 5,526,600 bytes, read 962 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

I think the URL to the database is incorrect but I don't know what should I supply for the URL. The credentials are to the cPanel and not to the database, maybe this is the issue?

I would like to get some help.

Comment: You appear to be using all of the wrong information.  You are not connecting to cPanel or phpMyAdmin through phpstorm, you are connecting to the database directly.  Database host, database user and database password... JDBC has no idea how to talk to phpMyAdmin, cPanel or any other web management console designed for user interaction via the browser.

Comment: @AlexBarker Thanks for your response. 
So how can I get connection to my database in the myphpadmin via phpstorm? It is possible?

Comment: You need to use the hostname/ip and port of the mysql database that myphpadmin is connecting to.  I don't know where this is displayed in myphpadmin, but it's in there somewhere.  Use a user / password in the database that has sufficient access.  You should be able to find/create this in the users table of the database.  You need to make sure the database is publicly accessible via that ip/port combination, if not, you will need to use ssh port forwarding or a VPN to connect.

Comment: @GabiMaimoni You need to connect via SSH to your hosting server where your files are first (web server). Such login instructions will be somewhere in your cPanel details (usually under SSH or similarly named section). If not -- contact your hosting company. Once connected, you can then use whatever DB connection details you are using in your actual website code (PHP I assume) as it will be "local" connection. PhpStorm allows to connect to MySQL database via SSH tunnel.

Comment: have you reached any solution on this yet? If yes please help me.